# How to create output column chart in pdf in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, pdf-generation

I want to create column chart in laravel 5.2 and I want chart output on PDF file instead of blade.php file. Is there any way to do calculation  on blade.php and write output(chart) on pdf file. I want to generate a students report card module in which the output(marksheet and progress graph)  will be in pdf format to be mailed to student.

Thanks.

Comment: i think you can use javascript to help you do this. Example: http://www.highcharts.com/, hope this help you

Comment: @Sweety, can you check the answer that I provided below and accept it if it works?

Answer (score 2):

I made it using **Laravel Snappy.**

**Installation:-**
*for X86 systems:-*

```
$ composer require h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-i386 0.12.x
$ composer require h4cc/wkhtmltoimage-i386 0.12.x
```

for X64 systems:-

```
$ composer require h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64 0.12.x
$ composer require h4cc/wkhtmltoimage-amd64 0.12.x
```

Now we should install Laravel Snappy it’s self.

```
$ composer require barryvdh/laravel-snappy
```

And After updating composer, add the ServiceProvider to the providers array in config/app.php:-

```
Barryvdh\Snappy\ServiceProvider::class,
```

Optionally you can use the Facade for shorter code. Add this to your facades:

```
'PDF' => Barryvdh\Snappy\Facades\SnappyPdf::class,
'SnappyImage' => Barryvdh\Snappy\Facades\SnappyImage::class,
```

Finally you can publish the config file:

```
$ php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Barryvdh\Snappy\ServiceProvider"
```

after that you need to go to config/snappy.php:-

and It to be like this:-

```
<?php
return array(
    'pdf' => array(
        'enabled' => true,
        'binary' => base_path('vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64'),
        'timeout' => false,
        'options' => array(),
        'env'     => array(),
    ),
    'image' => array(
        'enabled' => true,
        'binary'  => 'vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltoimage-amd64/wkhtmltoimage',
        'timeout' => false,
        'options' => array(),
        'env'     => array(),
    ),
);
```

make a controller

```
$ php artisan make:controller ChartController
```

make a new route for the pdf;
    Route::get(‘/chartPdf’, ‘ChartController@index’);

and now in **ChartController.php :-**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class ChartController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $pdf = \PDF::loadView('chartjs');
        $pdf->setOption('enable-javascript', true);
        $pdf->setOption('javascript-delay', 5000);
        $pdf->setOption('enable-smart-shrinking', true);
        $pdf->setOption('no-stop-slow-scripts', true);
        return $pdf->download('chart.pdf');
    }
}
```

and there is what your blade should be like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style>
        .pie-chart {
            width: 900px;
            height: 500px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>
    {{-- make sure you are using http, and not https --}}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function init() {
            google.load("visualization", "1.1", {
                packages: ["corechart"],
                callback: 'drawCharts'
            });
        }
        function drawCharts() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
                ['Coding', 11],
                ['Eat', 1],
                ['Commute', 2],
                ['Looking for code Problems', 4],
                ['Sleep', 6]
            ]);
            var options = {
                title: 'My Daily Activities',
            };
            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="init()">
    <div id="piechart" class="pie-chart"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

this answer was based on my article at medium.com here is the link for more information 
https://medium.com/@almestaadmicadiab/laravel-snappy-for-pdf-with-charts-e5c9b757d6dd

Comment: I assume this is based on your article? It’s okay to link to it, as long as the link is a supplement to the answer, and you make it clear that it’s your own article.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DOMPDF Laravel wrapper (https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf). This transforms your blade (which has the result data from your controller) to a PDF output.